# Parcel build command throws an error when trying to compile

Tags: sass, error-handling, compiler-errors, parceljs

When i run "npm run dev" it works like a charm, but when i start "npm run dev", this is what happens. I have parcel,sass and yeoman.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! parcel-sass-boilerplate@1.0.0 build: `parcel build src/index.html`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the parcel-sass-boilerplate@1.0.0 build script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\nikok\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-28T07_20_11_855Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **--no-minify** into script like this:

```
"build": "parcel build src/index.html --no-minify"
```